# How can I rigorously say that $(x-a)$ is a 'factor' of a function?

Tags: functions, definition

In the context of polynomials, the term 'factor' is unambiguous. But when it comes to functions, things get a bit murky.

For example:

> The function $$f(x)=(x-1)^2 e^x$$ has $(x-1)^2$ being a 'factor'.

However, if we go by that, then this should also be true.

> The function $$f(x)=(x-1)^2 \frac{1}{(x-1)^2} =1$$ has $(x-1)^2$ being a 'factor'.

Obviously the second example is a 'cheat' counter-example, but I am not absolutely certain how I can rigorously describe the expression $(x-1)^2$ in the function $f(x)=(x-1)^2 e^x$.

I am proposing the following extension of the definition of a factor, but will this do? Are there counter-examples?

> Let $f(x) = (x-x_0) g(x)$, where $g(x)$ is a continuous function at
>   $x=x_0$.
>
> If this is satisfied, then we say that $(x-x_0)$ is a
>   **factor** of $f(x)$.

Comment: To what end do you want to refer to $(x-1)^2$ as a "factor" of $(x-1)^2e^x$?  That is, what exactly do you want to _do_ with this definition?

Comment: @msm I don't know about your definition. Consider $\sqrt{x}$ and it's clear $x$ is not a factor of $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: You'll need to define "*factor of*" better. Is $x - 1$ for example a *factor of* $\sqrt{x} - 1$?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I believe what you are essentially trying to do is defined the order of vanishing of a function at some point $a$.

In short, you could say a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has $\alpha>0$ order of vanishing at $a$ provided $a$ is an isolated zero of $f$ and 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{|x-a|^\alpha} = \text{ nonzero constant }.
\end{align}

In the theory of complex analysis, one could actually show the order of vanishing at a zero of an analytic function is actually of integer order.

Comment: That's correct, but somewhat different from what the question asked. For example $1$ is a simple zero of $\sin(x-1)$ but it would be odd to call $x-1$ a *factor of* $\sin(x-1)$. The straight answer, I believe, is that the "*factor of*" concept simply doesn't extend from polynomials to arbitrary functions.

Comment: Sure it's okay to say $x-1$ is a factor of $\sin(x-1)$ since $\sin(x-1)= \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n(x-1)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$.

Comment: JackyChong I've never seen terminology used that said that $x-1$ is a *factor of* $\sin(x-1)$. Plus, that would imply that "*factor of*" is equivalent to "*has a zero at*" which is already a well known, unambiguous description that doesn't really need new synonyms.

Comment: People would say factor out $x-1$ from $\sin(x-1)$. I think the terminology is standard in the literature.

Comment: JackyChong Again, I have never encountered it used it that way. Maybe you should post some links to examples of such usage, since it's not familiar, to me at least.

Comment: @dxiv Okay then just call it order of vanishing or whatever you like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_(complex_analysis)

Comment: Here's a more authoritative link http://www.jstor.org/stable/1967766?seq=5#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: JackyChong I won't argue the [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) of course. My point was that the question as asked (and your answer as posted) were about *real* functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ i.e. *not* complex *and* entire functions. I have not seen "*factor of*" being used in the context of arbitrary real functions, which is all I said.

Comment: What makes complex analytic function more special then real analytic function? I think we are getting nowhere. If you don't like calling $x-1$ a factor of $\sin(x-1)$ then call it something else.

Comment: JackyChong If *you* do like calling $x-1$ a *factor of* $sin(x-1)$ then by all means keep at it. Just make it plain clear to the unsuspecting reader that it's your personal preference, and not commonly accepted usage. That was my point, remains so, and I won't repeat it further.